# AES Encryption / Decryption doesnt match

Tags: java, security, encryption

I have implemented AES - Decryption method as below - which works perfect. (I receive Encrypted text from other program)

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, byte[] keyValue)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] inputArr = Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
            SecretKeySpec skSpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
            int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(inputArr, blockSize));
            byte[] dataToDecrypt = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArr, blockSize, inputArr.length);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skSpec, iv);
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt);
            return new String(result, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

While I Encrypt text (before send it to other program) using below code is not generating expected output (If I use above decryption program to validate it just returns null)

```
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt,  String key)
    {
        try
        {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB/NoPadding");
            int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(Arrays.copyOf(strToEncrypt.getBytes(), blockSize));
            byte[] dataToDecrypt = Arrays.copyOfRange(strToEncrypt.getBytes(), blockSize, strToEncrypt.getBytes().length);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: The decrypt() method expects the encrypted bytes to contain a block with the IV, followed by the actual encrypted bytes. But the encrypt() method only generated the encrypted bytes. Also, you're transforming the string into bytes using your default platform encoding (`strToEncrypt.getBytes(),`), but you transforming back the bytes to a String using UTF8 (`new String(result, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`).

Comment: also you're using a 'Basic' Base64 encoder, but a URL decoder; these are not compatible.

Comment: Im including IV in the encryption,  cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv); byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(dataToDecrypt); is it not the right way?

Comment: After merging two byte[] It works !!

Comment: Your encrypt should be returning cipher text and IV.  Your decrypt should be taking in the IV as input.  That will help make it work, but if you want it to be secure, then you should choose your IV using SecureRandom().  Google for top 10 developer crypto mistakes.